# Adding an alertdialog to a view file

Tags: java, android, view, android-alertdialog

I am modifying a source code I had found. Normally when I make the UI I do it with the xml.
In this case it is all done in a java file (public class SplashMenuView extends View).

There is an onTouchEvent where something happens when something is pressed. I tried modifying it so that it shows an alertdialog instead, which would take me to another activity.
The problem is that

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(HERE);
```

I have trying adding what is required there and everything makes it crash or just gives error.

Usually I just add the name of this activity, but apparently it is not possible here.

I saw a code where they added:

```
private Activity thisActivity;
```

I tried this and inserted the activity that runs with this (SplashMenu) into that and inserting that into the uilder, but it just crashes.

Any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: your class extends View not activity. so you need activity pass activity context and then use the same for alertdialog initialization

Comment: @Raghunandan I'm sorry, I am just a beginner. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? I don't understand

Comment: why don't you check my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you have

```
public class SplashMenuView extends View
```

So in Activity class

```
new SplashMenuView(ActivityName.this);
```

Then

```
 Context mcontext; 
   public SplashMenuView(Context context)
   {
      mcontext =context; 
   }
```

Then

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(mcontext);
```

You can also use

`public final Context getContext ()`

Returns the context the view is running in, through which it can access the current theme, resources, etc.

```
Context mcontext; 
public SplashMenuView()
{
      mcontext =getContext();
}
```

Then

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(mcontext);
```

Comment: How would you do it then so it went to another activity instead?

Comment: @Marshall in another activity you can use `ActivityName.this`. can use activity context;

Answer (score 0):

If you are subclassing `View` you can get the context it is running in using [getContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext%28%29).